# Elementary os 6 and macbook 2,1

Tags: efi

I want to install a elementary os 6 on my macbook 2,1.

Unfortunately the software i staller loads a efi 64 bit bootloader into the harddrive which makes the booting progress impossible on macbook 2,1.

Yes apple did that 34 bit efi bootloader on a 64bit working software for the reason to make it hard for me to use my macbook in the future and to give me the feeling to buy a new one to avoid anger.

But i don’t want to give up. There must be an person on this world who can tell me how to change the iso file so that the 64 efi bootloader in the installing process gets removed by an 32 bit efi bootlader.

Please give me a hint for a website or a instruction how to change the bootloader file inside of the iso file from elementary os6.

Thank you!

Comment: Three questions for you: (1) How much RAM is installed? (2) Are you using the original 500GB hard drive or have you upgraded to an SSD? (3) Are you trying to dual-boot or run *only* Elementary OS?

Comment: Hi! It is a ssd from kingston with 120gb. The partition is okay. It installed it to the harddrive bit with an wrong efi which doesn’t fit to the macbook 2,1 architecture. There is 4gb ram installed and i want to use only elementary os 6.

Comment: [this guide](https://www-ubuntizando-com.translate.goog/instalando-elementaryos-macbook-21-2007/?_x_tr_sl=es&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=es&_x_tr_pto=nui) can help you.

Comment: Hi! I read your hint maccer. As i understood it right the only issue is, that i do need to test it and not to restart?